# Generate Identicon using JDenticon

Tags: javascript, html, identicon

I try to use the [JDenticon](https://jdenticon.com/) API (see [JDenticon API](https://jdenticon.com/#api)) to generate an identicon using Javascript and have the picture displayed on a basic HTML site. Afterwards I want to get the image using Java. But for now I just want the image to be displayed on a HTML-document.

Here is the code of my **test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jdenticon/1.3.2/jdenticon.min.js" async></script>

        <canvas width="200" height="200" data-jdenticon-hash="ff8adece0631821959f443c9d956fc39">
        Fallback text for browsers not supporting canvas</canvas>

        <svg width="200" height="200" data-jdenticon-hash="ff8adece0631821959f443c9d956fc39">
        Fallback text for browsers not supporting inline svg</svg>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when viewing **test.html** in Firefox there is no picture, why is that? I feel like I'm missing something really important but I canot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed https:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jdenticon/1.3.2/jdenticon.min.js" async></script>

        <canvas width="200" height="200" data-jdenticon-hash="ff8adece0631821959f443c9d956fc39">
        Fallback text for browsers not supporting canvas</canvas>

        <svg width="200" height="200" data-jdenticon-hash="ff8adece0631821959f443c9d956fc39">
        Fallback text for browsers not supporting inline svg</svg>

    </body>
</html>
```